# Is there a way i can use the webview.postURL on xamarin.forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, webview, http-post

I'm creating an app wrapping my website with Xamarin.forms. I want to implement login page on my mobile app that will by pass the login on the website using webview.postURL. Does postURL works for both iOS and android ? or android only? If it only works on android is there a way to do it for both platform?

I'm new to xamarin and c#, example codes or a github link would help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it by using `CustomRenderer`.

> in Forms ,define a subclass of Webview

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace xxx
{
    public class MyWebview:WebView
    {
        public string data; //Parameters that you want to pass
        public string url;
        public MyWebview()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

in contentPage

```
public MainPage()
{
   InitializeComponent();

   Content = new StackLayout
     {
        Children =
          {
            new MyWebview()
             {
               url="your url",
               WidthRequest = 300,
               HeightRequest = 500,
               data = "userName=xxx"
              },
          },
          VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
          HorizontalOptions=LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand

      };
}
```

> in iOS project

```
using Foundation;
using UIKit;


using xxx;
using xxx.iOS;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(MyWebview),typeof(MyWebViewRenderer))]
namespace xxx.iOS
{
    public class MyWebViewRenderer:WebViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if(NativeView!=null)
            {

                var mywebview = Element as MyWebview;

                var request = new NSMutableUrlRequest(new NSUrl(new NSString(mywebview.url)));
                request.Body = mywebview.data;
                request.HttpMethod = "POST";
                LoadRequest(request);

            }
        }        

    }
}
```

**Notes**

For iOS 9 onwards and MacOS, if you wish to access unsecure sites you may need to configure or disable ATS

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
</dict>
```

> in Android Project

```
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Webkit;
using Android.Widget;

using xxx;
using xxx.Droid;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyWebview), typeof(MyWebViewRenderer))]
namespace xxx.Droid
{
    public class MyWebViewRenderer:WebViewRenderer
    {
        public MyWebViewRenderer(Context context):base(context)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if(Control!=null)
            {
                var mywebview = Element as MyWebview;

                var postData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mywebview.data);
                Control.PostUrl(mywebview.url, postData);

            }

        }

    }
}
```

For more detail about custom renderer you can refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/).

Answer (score 0):

**POST Request Over Webview**
**For WkWebview**

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(PaymentWebview), typeof(PaymentWebViewRenderer))]
namespace MMFInvestorApp.iOS.Utils
{
    public class PaymentWebViewRenderer : WkWebViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

```
        if (NativeView != null)
        {
            var request = new NSMutableUrlRequest(new NSUrl(new NSString(paymentwebview.url))); //Your Url
            request.HttpMethod = "POST";
            request.Body = NSData.FromString(paymentwebview.data); //Data for POST
            request["Content-Length"] = req.Body.Length.ToString();
            request["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded charset=utf-8";
            LoadRequest(request);
        }

    }


}
```

}

**For UIWebview (Deprecated from April 2020**

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(PaymentWebview), typeof(PaymentWebViewRenderer))]
namespace MMFInvestorApp.iOS.Utils
{
    public class PaymentWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

```
        if (NativeView != null)
        {
            var paymentwebview = Element as PaymentWebview;
            var request = new NSMutableUrlRequest(new NSUrl(new NSString(paymentwebview.url)));//Your Url
            request.Body = paymentwebview.data; //Data for POST
            request.HttpMethod = "POST";
            LoadRequest(request);
        }

    }


}
```

}